# Save image into gallery in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, gallery

I try to save an image to gallery from a chat. I utilise for that gallery_saver package that does not helpfull. Please advise a proven package to save image into gallery. Or suggest how to fix the issue with method implementation.

```
void _saveNetworkImage(String url) async {
try {
GallerySaver.saveImage(url).then<void>((bool? success) {
if (success ?? false) {
GetIt.I
.get<NotificationService>()
.showSnackBar(context, S.current.image_saved_to_gallery);
} else {
GetIt.I
.get<NotificationService>()
.showSnackBar(context, S.current.error_image_saving_to_gallery);
}
}).onError((error, stackTrace) {
GetIt.I
.get<NotificationService>()
.showSnackBar(context, S.current.error_image_saving_to_gallery);
});
} catch (e) {
GetIt.I
.get<NotificationService>()
.showSnackBar(context, S.current.error_image_saving_to_gallery);
rethrow;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `path_provider` package([link](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)) for getting the local storage data and `dio`([link](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)) or `http`([link](https://pub.dev/packages/http)) to get and save the image to the local storage.

Here's an example:

```js
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

var response = await http.get(imgUrl);
Directory tempDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
File file =  File(join(tempDirectory.path, 'image.png'));
file.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);
```

Also, there's another package called `image_gallery_saver`([link](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver)) that makes saving images an easy task. You can checkout there package because we have to initially setup for some files. After that you can use this method to save image to the gallery.

```js
_save() async {
   var response = await Dio().get(
           "https://ss0.baidu.com/94o3dSag_xI4khGko9WTAnF6hhy/image/h%3D300/sign=a62e824376d98d1069d40a31113eb807/838ba61ea8d3fd1fc9c7b6853a4e251f94ca5f46.jpg",
           options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes));
   final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
           Uint8List.fromList(response.data),
           quality: 60,
           name: "hello",
         );
   print(result);
  }
```